# how install surprise on conda

Tags: installation, anaconda, conda

"pip install surprise" gives an error during installation. I can't install it from the Python interpreter part as well.

I wanted to create a new environment in anaconda and install surprise, but it wasn't there either.

Comment: As per [docs](https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise#installation), it goes by `scikit-surprise` in both PyPI and Conda Forge.

Comment: The specified methods could not be loaded in PyCharm and there was a problem. However, it was later resolved as I indicated.

Answer (score 0):

firstly go to anaconda command prompt and type:
"`conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise`",
after that open Python Interpreter and install "`surprise`" again.